# Set height on all images in list with specific class

Tags: html, css

I need to ask, how to set height on all images which are on specific list and class.

I have HTML:

```
<li class="product-category product first">
<a href="#"><img src="url-to-image"></a></li>
```

And I tried to do it with this code sample, but without working:

```
li.product-category product>img {
```

height: 10px !important;
}

Where is the problem? How to change CSS to work it properly? I need to change height on all images with class **product-category**.

Thank you for help, I think, it will be small improvement, but I do not know, which.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Do you mean width or height? Because in title you ask about height and in css you have width.

Comment: probably just need to change it from `li.product-category product>img` to `li.product-category.product img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li.product-category product>img` selects all images that are direct children of  elements `<product>` inside `li`-s with  'product-category' class. It is weird.

Try `li.product-category img` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The ">" in CSS selector means immediate child and you want to select ing, which has an a tag before.

I also changed it to height, according your question.

It should be like:

```
li.product-category > a > img {
    height: 10px !important;
}
```

*or* if you want any `<img>`, then:

```
li.product-category img {
    height: 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your css selector to `li.product-category product img`
Your current selector set css for all `<img>` elements whose parents is `li.product-category product` but in your case it's parent is `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

In css multiple selectors from the same tag don't have spaces between them.

Instead of `li.product-category product` try `li.product-category.product`.

After that u used `>img` which means direct child, but u have a link as direct child. Try to change to `>a>img`

Example:
`li.product-category.product>a>img {
height: 10px !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
li.product-category product>img {
   height: 10px !important; 
}
```

Issue here is that you forgot to add a "." in front of the "product" class, as well as added a space in front of this class (which css interprets as "product" is a child of ".product-category"). 
In general, it's a good practice to use less css selectors, it looks less cluttered as well as easier to override when needed:

```
.product-category img {
   height: 10px;
}
```

If you have to add "!important" to set height for the image, it means you either set image height in your css globally OR you already styled this same element else where..